# jQuery hover problem due to z-index

Tags: jquery, css, events, hover, z-index

I want to trigger a hover event for an element using jQuery, but I have an semi-transparent png positioned over the element using z-index.  Is there any way to tell jQuery to ignore the png and trigger the hover event for the element underneath it?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you are using a modern browser that supports css3, try adding this line to the css rule for the transparent png: `pointer-events: none;`
It basically tells the browser to ignore all mouse events on this element.

For example:

```
img
{
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/css/pointer-events

Alternatively if your targeted browser does not support css3, you can capture the mouse event and then fire a new one on the underlying element.

for example if your image id is #img and your underlying element id is #elem you may do this:

```
$("#elem").hover(function(e){
     $("#img").mouseenter(e);
});
```

You might have to mess with this a little depending on how your DOMs are set up, here's the documentation http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/

Comment: thanks! that worked, i suppose for non-modern browsers it just won't work, huh?

Comment: I just edited my answer with a jQuery solution, which might work for older browsers :)

Comment: awesome Razor. How do you know this kind of stuff ? This is the kind of knowledge really useful and at all unknown. GG mate

Comment: A lot of digging through css3 documentations. :P The MDC (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) is a good place to start.

Comment: Nice solution @RazorStorm! But a div can be over another 2 smallers elements, and we don't know what div to trigger the mouseover. Do you have any ideia to do that?