# How do I trigger a mouseenter (or any mouse) event on list items within a div with a z-index?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mouseevent, z-index

Every time I click on the list items only the z-index layer gets the mouse event. CSS has no trouble detecting the mouse hovering over the list item but I need jquery to display an image after retrieving the background-image from the list item's css.

For your convenience, I recreated it at jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VaDb6/

I've also tried this: 
[jQuery hover problem due to z-index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3517427/jquery-hover-problem-due-to-z-index)

But this just made everything else clickable in the back, which is exactly what
I don't want and the reason why I made the div with a z-index.

I've also tried giving each child a z-index but still no response from the list items.

I will greatly appreciate any suggestions or guidance. Thanks in advance!

Comment: check this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/VaDb6/5/)

Comment: @user108, sorry this was not what I wanted...I needed each individual li to trigger a mouse event.

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with the z-index, what is happening is that the events are binded when your page loads, and the freshly inserted divs don't have events attached to them. Here's how to fix it:

```
$('div.gallery_shots li').on('click', function () {
    // take the ancestor's html
    var html = $(this).parent().parent().next().html();

    $('div#layerZ').html(html + '<div id="debug"></div>').show();
});

$('div#layerZ').on('click', function () {
$('div#debug').append('layerZ...');
});


$('div#layerZ')
    .on("click", "li", function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        alert('li clicked');
    })
    .on("mouseenter", "li", function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();

    //$('div#layerZ div.gallery_pictures li.current').removeClass('current');
    //$(this).addClass('current');

    //var url = $(this).css('background-image');
    //url = url.replace('url(', '').replace('-thumb', '').replace(')', '');

    //$('div#layerZ div.large_gallery').html('<img src="'+url+'"></img>');

      $('div#debug').append('mouseenter event success!!!<br />');
});
```

With `$('div#layerZ').on("click", "li", function(e) {...}` you're telling the parent to listen on clicks done specifically on `li`. Since `#layerZ` exists at load time there's no problem binding the event.​

http://jsfiddle.net/LbqUC/