# Passing hover to elements below in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have several elements below one transparent element(it has some things in it that are visible though). But it seems the padding is not allowing the mouse events through. I have it so when the mouse hovers over one of the lower elements, it changes color, then when it leaves, it slowly turns back to its original color. But for the areas where the element above it covers them, the hover doesn't go through. Does anyone know how to get those events to pass through to lower elements?

HTML

```
<body>
<div id="background">
    <canvas class="gridBox" id="grid1x1"></canvas>
    <canvas class="gridBox" id="grid2x1"></canvas>
    <canvas class="gridBox" id="grid3x1"></canvas>
    ...
    <canvas class="gridBox" id="grid18x8"></canvas>
</div>
<div id="header">
    <p id="logo"><img src="img/logo.png"></p>
</div>  
<div id="content">
    <p>Nothing here yet</p>
</div>  
<div id="footer">
</div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
body,html{
padding:0;
margin:0;
}
#background{
padding:0;
margin:0;
width:110%;
height:100%;
z-index:-1;
position:fixed;
top:0;
left:0;
overflow:visible;
line-height: 0;
}
.gridBox{
margin:0;
padding:0;
height:50px;
width:50px;
border:1px solid #000000;
background:black;
transition:background-color 1s linear;
}
.gridBox:hover{
background-color:green;
transition:background-color 0s linear;
}
```

Comment: can you show the code?

Answer (score -1):

Since you did not post your code, I guess that you are working with something like light box, hover parent element and making animation.
I recommend you to look at this question has been resolved
[jQuery hover problem due to z-index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3517427/jquery-hover-problem-due-to-z-index)

Answer (score -1):

I think what you are looking for is this:

```
.gridBox:hover, .gridBox:hover * {
  background-color:green;
  transition:background-color 0s linear;
}
```

It just selects the .gridBox plus any child on the condition 
that the user is hovering .gridBox

Comment: the issue is that elements that are above span horizontally/vertically and still are in front the gridBox elements. They appear transparent but they are still in front.

Comment: I can't make sense of your comment, since your code doesn't make any element transparent. Maybe your code is incomplete?